# SQL querying for all rows with matching keys

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to sql, so i'll try to explain this as best as I can, but I'm clearnly missing some terminology

Basically I have a sql table set up like this

```
TABLE_NAME = locations
`pri_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`pri_att` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`value` float DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pri_id`,`pri_att`)
```

What I want to do is retrieve a list of all the rows which share a PRI_ID

For ex:

```
PRI_ID, PRI_ATT, VALUE
1       DIST     2
PRI_ID, PRI_ATT, VALUE
1       ALT      100
PRI_ID, PRI_ATT, VALUE
2       LAT      10
PRI_ID, PRI_ATT, VALUE
2       LONG     100
PRI_ID, PRI_ATT, VALUE
2       ALT      10
```

And what I'd like to be returned is `[[ROW_1, ROW_2], [ROW_3, ROW_4, ROW_5]]`

My sudo code for building this list is:

```
final_list = []
for x in 'SELECT DISTINCT pri_id FROM locations':
    final_list.append('SELECT * FROM locations WHERE pri_id==x')
```

I'm trying to get better at sql so I was wondering if sql has a better way to do this. Like joining a table onto itself

Comment: First of all, I am not sure why your question has `sqlalchemy` tag.
If you are new to `SQL`, it might be the case that using `sqlalchemy` is something you should wait for.
In any event, if you indeed are interested in the `sqlalchemy` usage of the database pattern you described, then take a look at the [Vertical Attribute Mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.vertical) examples.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The following sql query should do the job:

```sql
select * from locations
where pri_id in
  (select l2.pri_id from locations l2 group by l2.pri_id having count(*) > 1)
order by pri_id
```